# selecting a row as first row without using order by in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example:

```
id  name  agreement
32  fahid   52
43  nahid   51
31  zal     52
```

want to select by agreement but i want to keep top for a given `id`, if i use `order by` then always id is sorted.
if i search with `agreement=52` and `id=32` then expected result:

```
32 fahid 52
31 fahid 52
```

Comment: If you want a specific order of the output you have to use `order by`. If no column(s) in the table can be used to get the order you want than you can do nothing.

Comment: the title is so misleading.. `without using order by in SQL server`..

Comment: Please post your select statement so I can give you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use multiple fields in order by like 
`order by id,agreement`

Comment: check the title.. I don't know if this is the answer for his problem

Comment: although he says without using orderby which is not at possible in my opinion, but when you read his question, this makes sense to me..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @agreement INT

SET @id = 32
SET @agreement = 52

SELECT [id]
, (SELECT [name] FROM Table1 WHERE [id] = @id) AS [name]
, [agreement] FROM Table1 
WHERE [agreement] = @agreement
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8104/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
id  name    agreement
32  fahid   52
31  fahid   52
```

Answer (score 0):

use LIMIT in mysql

MySQL Syntax

```
SELECT column_name(s)FROM table_name WHERE (condition) LIMIT number;
```

Example

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE agreement=52 LIMIT 5;
```

Oracle Syntax

```
SELECT column_name(s)FROM table_name WHERE ROWNUM <= number;
```

Example

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE ROWNUM <=5;
```

Comment: The question is tagged SQL Server.